# Why do my tests not pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I am using Michael Hartl's book to learn rails. I am covering a section about uniqueness validation. I have copied it word for word (as it seems), and it is still not passing. Any thoughts?

User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255},
    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX},
    uniqueness: case_sensitive: false
end
```

Test/User_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

    def setup
        @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
    end

test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
end
```

Error:

Error:

```
UserTest#test_name_should_be_present:
SyntaxError: /home/benjamin/Desktop/Projects/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
    uniqueness: case_sensitive: false
                               ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write :

```
uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Because

```
{a: b: :c}
```

is a Syntax error.

Is it :

```
{:a=>{:b=>:c}}
```

or

```
{{:a=>:b}=>:c}
```

?

Comment: I'll accept your answer as correct when I am allowed to.

Comment: Is that a mistake with Michael, or has rails changed? I have written it down exactly as he did.

Comment: I can only find `uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }` in https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users

Comment: I bought the paperback copy ;)

Comment: It might be a typo that has been corrected online since.

Comment: Just curious : why aren't you allowed to accept an answer?

Comment: If I click on it, it says you can accept an answer in X minutes, and it doesn't allow me until the timer is up. We are down to 2 minutes now. An online dictatorship.